# c# combobox set the value using text

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, windows-forms-designer

I have a combobox `farmRegion` that I fill in this way

```
private void fillRegionData() {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
            farmRegion.ValueMember = "ID";
            farmRegion.DisplayMember = "Description";
            farmRegion.SelectedValue = "ID";
            for (int i = 0; i < StaticData.RegionNames.Count; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(StaticData.RegionValues[i], StaticData.RegionNames[i]);
            }
            farmRegion.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

where `StaticData.RegionNames` is:

```
public static List<string> RegionNames = new List<string>() { "Select Region", "EASTERN", "WESTERN", "NORTHERN", "EASTERN2", "NORTHERN", "MIDDLE" };
```

and `StaticDate.RegionValues` is

```
public static List<string> RegionValues = new List<string>() { "-10", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" };
```

when I save the form, I save the **text** of the combobox, **not the value** (this is a requirement issue).

now I want to reload the comboxbox again.
I already know the text but I need to make the combobox fires and the option text is already selected.

I tried this:

```
farmRegion.Text = myText
```

but still the first option is selected.

Comment: The text in the combobox represents its value. Would you like to set text and make it represent a different value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before setting the text `farmRegion.Text = myText` put a break point and checks the `combobox` datasource, and ensure `myText` is present in `combobox`.

If you handled any `events of combobox` put a break point on that events and check what happend after the execution of `farmRegion.Text = myText` statement.

These two steps doen't solve your issue then find out the index of your text value as

```
int index = farmRegion.FindString(myText);
farmRegion.SelectedIndex = index;
```

Comment: perhaps little late, but can we set text as some random value? for example `farmRegion.Text='some value that isn't in datasource'`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
farmRegion.SelectedIndex = farmRegion.FindStringExact(myText)
```

*Another Approach:*
Note: This may throw `argumentexception` if the item was not found.

```
farmRegion.SelectedIndex = farmRegion.Items.IndexOf(myText);
```

Comment: for no reasons I know, the .Text is working again :) :),

Comment: the issue may related to the datasource.. may be the text will not be present in the datasource..

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
DataRow[] drs = ((DataTable)cmb.DataSource).Select("Description='" + myText + "'");
if (drs.Length > 0)
{
    cmb.SelectedValue = drs[0]["ID"].ToString();
}
else
{
    //Value not found
}
```

**EDITED:**

Sometime when you set the text of combobox will not return the value of `ValueMember` from `SelectedValue` it may return `null` and `SelectedIndex` may return `-1`.