# Problem getting selected row values to combo box from datagridview cell click in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms Form1 and Form2.
I am facing problem loading Datagridview cell value of Form1 to the combo box of Form2 on cell double click event as show in the screenshot.
using below code, text box values getting properly from the row i had selected but combo box shows empty.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex != -1 && e.ColumnIndex != -1)
    {
        Form2 fo = new Form2();
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        fo.textBox1.Text = row.Cells["firstNameGV"].Value.ToString();
        fo.textBox2.Text = row.Cells["lastNameGV"].Value.ToString();
        fo.comboBox1.Text = row.Cells["deptGV"].Value.ToString();
        fo.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

[screenshot of forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODVKZ.jpg)

how do i get the values in combo box. (p.s: combo box on Form2 is filled from database on form_loadevent values can also be seen in the attachment.)

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadItems();
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: I think that https://stackoverflow.com/a/25057845/4180382 will shed light on your problem. Moreover, I would remove the sql-server tag from your question, this is a C# winform issue

Comment: `int index = fo.comboBox1.FindString(row.Cells["deptGV"].Value.ToString());
                fo.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index;`
index here returning -1

Comment: So it doesn't find the text in the combo box. That's why it can't select it I'd say?

Comment: but the text is present which is loaded from the database can be seen in data table in the debug

Comment: and if i remove `comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;` from form_onload_event
first value is showing always by default

Comment: And if you Trim() like so : int index = fo.comboBox1.FindString(row.Cells["deptGV"].Value.ToString().Trim() );
Other question: does row.Cells["deptGV"].Value.ToString().Trim() evaluate to a value at all?

Comment: yes `row.Cells["deptGV"].Value.ToString().Trim()` is getting the value from the row which is selected.
but the index is -1 only

Comment: The combobox might not have finished loading yet, when clicking the value. That might also be the reason for not finding it.

Comment: @OleEHDufour yes.. you're right here. combo is loading after that click is the reason index getting -1. so how to load the combo first?

Comment: There are multiple solutions : You can always show Form2 when opening Form1 by putting     Form2 fo = new Form2();fo.ShowDialog(); in the constructor of Form1. You could also subscribe to an event in Form1 which is fired when the combobox has finised loading. Until such time you disable the gridview and show an hourglass. You put that event in Form2

Comment: @OleEHDufour thanks for your suggestions, i got it what i want but some other way. but the main idea came from you only.